# How to convert date format to total number of days?

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a yyyy-mm-dd data in a data frame to the total number of days from some date to put in my survival function.

I've already tried `as_date()` and `grepl()`, but I can't seem to get it to work since there are either too many NA values in my data frame or I'm doing something wrong.

```
Ref.date <- ymd("1941-08-24")
Date.MI <- ymd("Date.MI")
Day <- as.numeric(difftime(Date.MI, Ref.date))
```

I expect just the total number of days since 1941-08-24.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Try `Sys.Date() - as.Date("1941-08-24")`. Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output.  Also, if `DateMI` is an identifier, then, `ymd(Date.MI)` instead of quoting it

Comment: You don't need to convert to date format to use `difftime`. Besides, your `ymd()` example won't work as the variable name is quoted. This works: `as.numeric(difftime("2019-06-01", "2019-05-01"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`difftime()` gives you the option to specify the units for the resulting output.  So maybe try something like this

```
 as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct("1941-08-25"), as.POSIXct("1941-08-24"), units = c("days")))
```

Comment: I'm very sorry I have no idea what this means... I put it in R and got an output of -1...
I replaced it with:
as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct("Date.MI"), as.POSIXct("1941-08-24"), units = c("days")))
but get an error.

Comment: @MichelKiflen. As it is already commented by two people, don't quote the `Date.MI`, not sure why you stilll do that

Comment: The first argument in `difftime()` should be the later date, and the second argument the earlier date in order for the result to be a positive number.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still getting the error:
Error in as.POSIXct.default(Date.MI) :
  do not know how to convert 'Date.MI' to class “POSIXct”

Comment: You have defined `Date.MI` to be of class `Date` (check the documentation for the `ymd()` function and specifically the `tz` argument).  This is okay because `difftime()` works just as well with `Date` class as with `POSIXct` class.  So you should use `as.numeric(difftime(Date.MI, Ref.date, units = c("days")))`

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve it:

as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(Date.MI[[1]]), as.POSIXct("1941-08-24"), units = c("days")))

There were square brackets needed since that refers to the first column.